# Help with proving $ \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_{k} x^{k}=\frac{c_{0}+\left(c_{1}-A c_{0}\right) x}{1-A x-B x^{2}} $ when $c_{k}=A c_{k-1}+B c_{k-2}$

Tags: summation, power-series

I need some help with this question. So far i've spent a few hours on it and got a few noteworthy connections as can be seen below. But I am not sure how to progress any further. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction (Without giving the immediate answer). I've gotten it in a more understanding form but the equation still depends on a previous $c_k$ and the goal to eventually get it into and equation is to get it in a form that does not depend on previous $c_k$.
This is what I have so far.
Let $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_{k} x^{k}$ be a power series, such that for all $k \geq 2$ the relation
$$
c_{k}=A c_{k-1}+B c_{k-2}
$$
holds true, where $A, B \in \mathbb{R}$.
Show that for all $x$ in the convergence interval of the series, we have
$$
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_{k} x^{k}=\frac{c_{0}+\left(c_{1}-A c_{0}\right) x}{1-A x-B x^{2}}
$$
We need to find a representation of $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_{k} x^{k}$ in terms of $c_0,c_1,A,B$ so we can transform the sums into equations and combine into the fraction above.
To find a connection we write out the first 7 terms of the sum and for each $k$ factor out $c_0$ and $c_1$ to get the following table.

$$\begin{array}{|l|l|l|}
\hline k & c_{1} & c_{0} \\
\hline 2 & A & B \\
\hline 3 & A^{2}+B & A B \\
\hline 4 & A^{3}+2 A B & A^{2} B+B^{2} \\
\hline 5 & A^{4}+3 A^{2} B+B^{2} & A^{3} B+2 A B^{2} \\
\hline 6 & A^{5}+4 A^{3} B+2 A B^{2} & A^{4} B+3 A^{2} B^{2}+B^{3} \\
\hline
\end{array}$$
Starting from $k>2$ we can see a connection between $c_1$ and $c_0$ and their previous terms.

\begin{equation}
    c_{1,k} = Ac_{1,k-1} + c_{0,k-1}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    c_{0,k} = Bc_{1,k-1} 
\end{equation}
We know that $c_k=c_{1,k}+c_{0,k}$ so we can substitute (1) and (2) into this equation and factor to get.

\begin{equation}
    c_{k} = c_{1,k-1}(A+B) + c_{0,k-1}
\end{equation}

Comment: Just a suggestion: Let $S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^k$, and just plug in the value of $c_k$ in terms of its previous terms $c_k = Ac_{k-1}+Bc_{k-2}$ (of course you can only do this when starting from $k=2$ in the sum); after that, re-organize the two series that you get in order to make $S$ appear again in the expression. You will end up with an expression involving $S$, and you will be able to isolate $S$ from there.

For example, $S = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_k x^k = c_0 + c_1x + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} c_{k+2} x^{k+2} = c_0 + c_1x + \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} [A c_{k+1} + B c_k] x^{k+2} = ...$

Comment: This suggestion can be turned into an answer

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion i was looking at it wrong at got the right answer now !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} C_k x^k$, $C_k=C_{k-1}+BC_{k-2}.$
then $$f(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}[ A C_{k-1} x^k + B C_{k-2} x^k].$$
In the first sum take $k-1=p$, in the second $k-2=q$, then
$$f(x)=A\sum_{p=-1}^{\infty} C_p x^{p+1}+ B\sum_{q=-2}^{\infty} C_q x^{q+2}$$
$$f(x)=A C_{-1}+Ax\sum_{p=0}^{\infty} C_p x^p + B C_{-2}+ B C_{-1} x +B x^2\sum_{q=0}^{\infty} C_q x^q$$
$$f(x)=Ax f(x)+B x^2 f(x)+A C_{-1}+B C_{-2} +B C_{-1} x$$
Using $C_0=A C_{-1}+BC_{-2}$ and $C_1=AC_0+BC_{-1}$, we re-write
$$(1-Ax-Bx^2) f(x)=C_0+B(C_1-AC_0)$$
$$\implies f(x)=\frac{C_0+B(C_1-AC_0)}{1-Ax-Bx^2}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}C_k x^k$$